# Martingale with Gaussian marginals that is not jointly Gaussian

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, gaussian

Let $X_0,X_1$ be random variables such that $E[X_1|X_0]=X_0$, $X_0 \sim \mathcal N (0, \sigma_0^2)$, and  $X_1 \sim \mathcal N (0, \sigma_1^2)$ (notice that $\sigma_0^2 \leq \sigma_1^2$ by the martingale condition).

I am wondering if the joint distribution of $(X_0,X_1)$ can be non-Gaussian under the above conditions (without the martingale condition, it is easy). And if so, could I see an example?

A Gaussian example (and it is unique) is given by the conditional distribution $X_1|X_0 \sim \mathcal N (X_0, \sigma_1^2 -\sigma_0^2)$

Comment: What about $X_0=X_1$? In this case, their joint distribution doesn't have a density, thus is not Gaussian.

Comment: See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308775/conditional-expectation-of-two-identical-marginal-normal-random-variables), "I believe there are bivariate distributions with Normal marginals, (nonzero) linear conditional expectation function, but which are not bivariate Normal. All these will correspond to copulas that produce linear conditional expectations. To produce such a counterexample, it suffices to produce one with zero conditional expectation and standard Normal marginals--you can then scale and mix it with any bivariate Normal distribution."